# PKCS#7 data payload unpacking with NodeJS?

Tags: ios, node.js, encryption, cryptography, pkcs#7

I'm working on an MDM NodeJS server for iOS. On the Apple docs, the following ruby code is given :

```
  p7sign = OpenSSL::PKCS7::PKCS7.new(req.body)
  store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
  p7sign.verify(nil, store, nil, OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY)
  signers = p7sign.signers
```

What would be the equivalent in NodeJS?
The idea is to access `p7sign.data` that contains an xml plist.

Is this possible using either `crypto` or an external node lib (`ursa`, etc)?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? Did you use crypto to achieve your goal ?

Answer (score 0):

A good option would be to use child_process to invoke openssl directly. I do that to validate iOS .mobileprovision files.

```
$ openssl smime -verify -in FILE -inform der
```

The openssl command needs to be the apple-provided (not from ports or homebrew) so that it can find signing certificates and CA's in the keychain.

I haven't tried this myself, but the node-forge library contains an implementation of many cryptographic algorithms.

https://npmjs.org/package/node-forge#pkcs7

Comment: `-inform der` is in case the file is in DER format (like .mobileprovision files), otherwise use `smime` or `pem`.

Comment: node-forge doesn't do pkcs7 verification at this time.